# Autotools and OpenSSL MD5/RAND_bytes undefined

Tags: c++, gcc, autotools

For some reason I am getting undefined symbols for MD5 and RAND_bytes in this one particular C++ file. OpenSSL has installed itself (libssl and libcrypto) to /usr/lib and /usr/include/openssl/.

```
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libeapgpsk.so.1" && ln -s "libeapgpsk.so.1.0.0" "libeapgpsk.so.1")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libeapgpsk.so" && ln -s "libeapgpsk.so.1.0.0" "libeapgpsk.so")
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libeapgpsk.a  eap-gpsk/eap_gpsk_fsm.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libeapgpsk.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libeapgpsk.la" && ln -s "../libeapgpsk.la" "libeapgpsk.la" )
depbase=`echo tests/md5_test.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
    g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"OpenDiameter\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"opendiameter\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0.7-i\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"OpenDiameter\ 1.0.7-i\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"vfajardo@tari.toshiba.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"opendiameter\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.7-i\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_IFADDRS_H=1 -DHAVE_SHADOW_H=1 -DHAVE__BOOL=1 -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H=1 -DHAVE_GETIFADDRS=1 -I.  -Wall -I/usr -I/usr -fno-strict-aliasing -I../include -I../libeap/include -DOS_LINUX -I/usr/include/openssl  -I/usr/include/openssl -MT tests/md5_test.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o tests/md5_test.o tests/md5_test.cxx &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
In file included from ../include/aaa_dictionary_api.h:45:0,
                 from ../include/aaa_parser_api.h:38,
                 from ../libeap/include/eap.hxx:54,
                 from tests/md5_test.cxx:45:
../include/framework.h:1653:7: warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration [enabled by default]
In file included from ../include/aaa_parser_api.h:38:0,
                 from ../libeap/include/eap.hxx:54,
                 from tests/md5_test.cxx:45:
../include/aaa_dictionary_api.h:58:1: warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration [enabled by default]
tests/md5_test.cxx: In constructor ‘EapTask::EapTask()’:
tests/md5_test.cxx:71:45: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
tests/md5_test.cxx: In constructor ‘PeerApplication::PeerApplication(EapTask&, ACE_Semaphore&)’:
tests/md5_test.cxx:418:72: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
tests/md5_test.cxx: In constructor ‘StandAloneAuthApplication::StandAloneAuthApplication(EapTask&, ACE_Semaphore&)’:
tests/md5_test.cxx:460:80: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
tests/md5_test.cxx: In constructor ‘BackendAuthApplication::BackendAuthApplication(EapTask&, ACE_Semaphore&, bool)’:
tests/md5_test.cxx:514:58: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
tests/md5_test.cxx: In constructor ‘PassThroughAuthApplication::PassThroughAuthApplication(EapTask&, ACE_Semaphore&, bool)’:
tests/md5_test.cxx:576:62: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -I/usr/include/openssl -L/usr/lib  -o md5_test tests/md5_test.o -ldl -lssl -lcrypto -lACE_SSL -lACE -lACEXML_Parser -lACEXML -lpthread -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lACEXML -lACEXML_Parser -ldl -lssl -lcrypto ../libeap/libeap.la ../libeap/libeaparchie.la ../libeap/libeapgpsk.la -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lACEXML -lACEXML_Parser -ldl -lssl -lcrypto
libtool: link: g++ -I/usr/include/openssl -o .libs/md5_test tests/md5_test.o  -L/usr/lib /usr/lib/libACE_SSL.so /usr/lib/libACE.so -lpthread ../libeap/.libs/libeap.so ../libeap/.libs/libeaparchie.so ../libeap/.libs/libeapgpsk.so -lboost_system -lboost_thread /usr/lib/libACEXML.so /usr/lib/libACEXML_Parser.so -ldl -lssl -lcrypto
../libeap/.libs/libeap.so: undefined reference to `MD5@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
../libeap/.libs/libeap.so: undefined reference to `RAND_bytes@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the Makefile.am responsible for this:

```
## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

srcdir = @srcdir@
VPATH = @srcdir@

AM_CPPFLAGS = @L_CPPFLAGS@ \
              -I@top_srcdir@/include \
              -I@top_srcdir@/libeap/include \
              -D@HOST_OS@
AM_LDFLAGS = @L_LDFLAGS@

if compile_EAPTLS
CORE_SRC = eapcore/eap_fsm.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_peerfsm.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_authfsm.cxx \
        eapcore/eap_standalone_authfsm.cxx \
        eapcore/eap_backend_authfsm.cxx \
        eapcore/eap_passthrough_authfsm.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_identity.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_method_registrar.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_policy.cxx \
        eapcore/eap_notification.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_md5.cxx 

CORE_HDR = include/eap_api.h \
        include/eap.hxx \
        include/eap_authfsm.hxx \
        include/eap_fsm.hxx \
        include/eap_identity.hxx \
        include/eap_log.hxx \
        include/eap_md5.hxx \
        include/eap_method_registrar.hxx \
        include/eap_notification.hxx \
        include/eap_parser.hxx \
        include/eap_peerfsm.hxx \
        include/eap_policy.hxx \
    include/eap_archie_crypto.hxx \
    include/eap_archie_fsm.hxx \
    include/eap_archie_parser.hxx \
    include/eap_archie.hxx \
    include/eap_gpsk_crypto.hxx \
    include/eap_gpsk_fsm.hxx \
    include/eap_gpsk_parser.hxx \
    include/eap_gpsk.hxx \
    include/eap_tls.hxx \
    include/eap_tls_mng.hxx \
    include/eap_tls_session.hxx \
    include/eap_tls_parser.hxx \
    include/eap_tls_fsm.hxx \
    include/eap_tls_xml_data.hxx \
    include/eap_tls_xml_parser.hxx \
    include/eap_tls_data_defs.hxx
else
CORE_SRC = eapcore/eap_fsm.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_peerfsm.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_authfsm.cxx \
        eapcore/eap_standalone_authfsm.cxx \
        eapcore/eap_backend_authfsm.cxx \
        eapcore/eap_passthrough_authfsm.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_identity.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_method_registrar.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_policy.cxx \
        eapcore/eap_notification.cxx \
    eapcore/eap_md5.cxx

CORE_HDR = include/eap_api.h \
        include/eap.hxx \
        include/eap_authfsm.hxx \
        include/eap_fsm.hxx \
        include/eap_identity.hxx \
        include/eap_log.hxx \
        include/eap_md5.hxx \
        include/eap_method_registrar.hxx \
        include/eap_notification.hxx \
        include/eap_parser.hxx \
        include/eap_peerfsm.hxx \
        include/eap_policy.hxx \
    include/eap_archie_crypto.hxx \
    include/eap_archie_fsm.hxx \
    include/eap_archie_parser.hxx \
    include/eap_archie.hxx \
    include/eap_gpsk_crypto.hxx \
    include/eap_gpsk_fsm.hxx \
    include/eap_gpsk_parser.hxx \
    include/eap_gpsk.hxx
endif

ARCHIE_SRC = eap-archie/eap_archie_fsm.cxx

GPSK_SRC = eap-gpsk/eap_gpsk_fsm.cxx

if compile_EAPTLS
TLS_SRC = eap-tls/eap_tls_mng.cxx \
          eap-tls/eap_tls_crypto.cxx \
          eap-tls/eap_tls_fsm.cxx \
          eap-tls/eap_tls_xml_data.cxx \
          eap-tls/eap_tls_xml_parser.cxx
endif

includedir = $(prefix)/include/opendiameter/eap
include_HEADERS = $(CORE_HDR)

sysconfdir = $(prefix)/etc/opendiameter/eap
sysconf_DATA = config/client.eap-tls.xml \
               config/server.eap-tls.xml

if compile_EAPTLS
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libeap.la libeaparchie.la libeapgpsk.la libeaptls.la
else
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libeap.la libeaparchie.la libeapgpsk.la
endif

libeap_la_SOURCES = $(CORE_SRC) $(CORE_HDR)
libeaparchie_la_SOURCES = $(ARCHIE_SRC)
libeapgpsk_la_SOURCES = $(GPSK_SRC)

if compile_EAPTLS
libeaptls_la_SOURCES = $(TLS_SRC)
endif

libeap_la_LIBADD = -ldl -lssl -lcrypto
libeap_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 1:0:0 -lssl -lcrypto
libeap_la_AR = $(AR) -qcs

libeaparchie_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 1:0:0 
libeaparchie_la_AR = $(AR) -qcs

libeapgpsk_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 1:0:0 
libeapgpsk_la_AR = $(AR) -qcs

if compile_EAPTLS
libeaptls_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 1:0:0 
libeaptls_la_AR = $(AR) -qcs
LDADD = @L_LIBS@ \
        $(top_builddir)/libeap/libeap.la \
        $(top_builddir)/libeap/libeaparchie.la \
        $(top_builddir)/libeap/libeapgpsk.la \
        $(top_builddir)/libeap/libeaptls.la \
        $(top_builddir)/libdiamparser/libdiamparser.la
else
LDADD = @L_LIBS@ \
        $(top_builddir)/libeap/libeap.la \
        $(top_builddir)/libeap/libeaparchie.la \
        $(top_builddir)/libeap/libeapgpsk.la
endif

if compile_EAPTLS
noinst_PROGRAMS = md5_test archie_test gpsk_test tls_test
else
noinst_PROGRAMS = md5_test archie_test gpsk_test
endif

md5_test_SOURCES = tests/md5_test.cxx -lssl -lcrypto

archie_test_SOURCES = tests/archie_test.cxx 

gpsk_test_SOURCES = tests/gpsk_test.cxx 

if compile_EAPTLS
tls_test_SOURCES = tests/tls_test.cxx
endif

EXTRA_DIST = config
```

I suspect autotools isn't doing something because I haven't specified it to do so.  Inside of the file md5_test.c, but it still errors.

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I dug into the libraries to see if there was versioning information and it led me to this very interesting predicament - openssl 1.0.0m when compiled with this command: ./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/etc/ssl --libdir=lib shared

Generates two sets of shared objects located in:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib
```

The shared objects in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ Produce a version (used objdump -T)

```
00000000001546b0 g    DF .text  0000000000000108  OPENSSL_1.0.0 PKCS7_to_TS_TST_INFO
```

The shared objects in /usr/lib produce this:

```
000000000012ee20 g    DF .text  000000000000000c  Base        BIO_new_CMS
```

How would one fix this because this seems highly unstandard....?

Comment: Is your `-lssl` finding an older version of `libssl` that does not contain the version 1.0.0 symbols (e.g. `MD5@OPENSSL_1.0.0`)?

Comment: I have openssl 1.0.0m compiled and installed so I would think so:               rbrash@megatron:~/Downloads/diameter-svn/cplusplus$ sudo nm -D /usr/lib/libcrypto.so | grep md5
00000000000db570 T EVP_md5
0000000000067c30 T md5_block_asm_data_order
rbrash@megatron:~/Downloads/diameter-svn/cplusplus$ sudo nm -D /usr/lib/libcrypto.so | grep MD5
0000000000067bb0 T MD5
00000000000679d0 T MD5_Final
0000000000067b00 T MD5_Init
00000000000679c0 T MD5_Transform
00000000000677a0 T MD5_Update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `-lssl -lcrypto` from the `LDFLAGS` for your libraries; the way the link editor works, `LDFLAGS` are passed before the object files, and that means they are discarded; in at least some version of the link editor, the libraries passed before object files are also "blacklisted", or to be precise, they get ignored when passed again.

You're passing `-lssl -lcrypto` twice in both `LDFLAGS` and `LIBADD` so you may be triggering that behaviour.